# $.get ajax method not working for state and city in laravel

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I want to access city by it's state.
This method was working before updating Laravel 5.7
Now it's not working

this is the error that I got:

```
jquery-3.3.1.js:9600 GET http://localhost/PTC/public/ajax-city=5 404 (Not Found)
```

web.php

```
Route::get('ajax-city','IndexController@ajaxCities')->name('ajax-city');
public function ajaxCities()
    {
        $state_id = Input::get('state_id');
        $cities   = City::where('state_id', '=', $state_id)->get();
        return response()->json($cities);
    }
```

my view:

```
<form id="accountForm" name="accountForm" action="{{route('profile')}}" method="post">
                            @csrf
    <select class="form-control" id="state" name="state_id" type="text" placeholder="استان">
    <option value="{{$userDetails->state_id ?? ''}}">{{$userDetails->state->title ?? 'انتخاب استان'}}</option>
     @foreach($states as $state)
        <option value="{{$state->id}}">{{$state->title}}</option>
     @endforeach
   </select>
   <select class="form-control" id="city" name="city_id">
       <option value="{{$userDetails->city_id ?? ''}}">{{$userDetails->city->title ?? 'انتخاب شهر'}}</option>
   </select>
 <button type="submit" class="btn iren-btn btn-block mt-1 mb-2">ثبت</button>
                        </form>
```

and script:

```
<script>
        //City choose
        $().ready(function () {
            $('#state').on('change', function (e) {
                var state_id = e.target.value;

                //AJAX
                $.get('ajax-city?state_id=' + state_id, function (data) {
                    //success data
                    $('#city').empty();
                    $.each(data, function (index, cityObj) {
                        $('#city').append('<option value="' + cityObj.id + '">' + cityObj.title + '</option>')
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

In "routes/web.php file:

```
    Route::get('ajax-city/{state_id}', 'IndexController@ajaxCities')
    ->where('state_id', '[0-9]+')
    ->name('ajax-city');
```

In "app/Http/Controllers/IndexController.php":

```
public function ajaxCities(Request $request)
{

    $state_id = $request->state_id;
    $cities   = City::where('state_id', '=', $state_id)->get();
    return response()->json($cities);
}
```

And change the script:

```
<script>
    //City choose
    $().ready(function () {
        $('#state').on('change', function (e) {
            var state_id = e.target.value;

            //AJAX
            $.get('ajax-city/' + state_id, function (data) {
                //success data
                $('#city').empty();
                $.each(data, function (index, cityObj) {
                    $('#city').append('<option value="' + cityObj.id + '">' + cityObj.title + '</option>')
                });
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```